# How to get a relative path in c

Tags: c

`pwd` prints the absolute path of the current working directory by using `getcwd()` function.

So, is there a function that returns relative path of the current working directory in c?

Comment: Relative to what?

Comment: In general, relative paths are relative to the current working directory. The current directory as a relative path is just `.`

Comment: "*relative*" is an adjective (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective), it refers to something. This "something" you do not tell us, so your question is incomplete.

Answer (score 3):

> So, is there a function that returns relative path of the current working directory in c?

*Relative paths* are usually relative to the current working directory. So your question doesn't really make sense.

The only answer valid would be:

```
const char *get_rel_cwd(void)
{
    return ".";
}
```

Comment: I learned C in university as my first programming language and I never understood of pointers correctly. May I ask why this function is a pointer?

Comment: The function is returning a C-string, which is defined as a pointer to a NUL-terminated array of char.